# How do I add Images to vertical timeline layout?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to teach myself how ot build a timeline and add images. I found this on W3. I want to add images left / right of each text-container displaying what is writte in the text.
I experimented around a lot trying to make it work but I dont completely understand. Also there are some parts within this code I dont completely understand yet. It would be helpful I think, if you could break it down into pieces are explain a little on what each code of line does. But my main problem is to add images next to (left or right) the text-containers. 
Thank you.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #474e5d;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.timeline {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.timeline::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 6px;
  background-color: white;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -3px;
}

.container {
  padding: 10px 40px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: inherit;
  width: 50%;
}

.container::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  right: -17px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 4px solid #FF9F55;
  top: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.left {
  left: 0;
}

.right {
  left: 50%;
}

.left::before {
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  right: 30px;
  border: medium solid white;
  border-width: 10px 0 10px 10px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent white;
}

.right::before {
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 30px;
  border: medium solid white;
  border-width: 10px 10px 10px 0;
  border-color: transparent white transparent transparent;
}

.right::after {
  left: -16px;
}

.content {
  padding: 20px 30px;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="timeline">
  <div class="container left">
    <div class="content">
      <h2>2017</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container right">
    <div class="content">
      <h2>2016</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the image to existing container using `<img>` tag.

```
<div class="container left">
   <div class="content">
    <h2>2017</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum..</p>
   </div>
   <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" /> <!-- image tag inside the container -->
 </div>
```

I added the below additional CSS and used [CSS flexbox layout](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```
/* Newly added CSS begin*/
.container {
  display: flex; /*this makes the container flexbox layout*/
}
.container.left .content {
   order: 2; /* order changes the content order within container */
   margin-left: auto; /* pushes the left content box to extreme left */
}
 .container.right .content {
    margin-right: auto;
 }
.container img {
 margin: 0 20px;
}
/* Newly added CSS ends */
```

Updated code is below:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #474e5d;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

/* Newly added CSS begin*/
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.container.left .content {
    order: 2;
    margin-left: auto;
}
.container.right .content {
   margin-right: auto;
}
.container img {
  margin: 0 20px;
}
/* Newly added CSS ends */

.timeline {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.timeline::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 6px;
  background-color: white;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -3px;
}

.container {
  padding: 10px 40px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: inherit;
  width: 50%;
}

.container::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  right: -17px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 4px solid #FF9F55;
  top: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.left {
  left: 0;
}

.right {
  left: 50%;
}

.left::before {
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  right: 30px;
  border: medium solid white;
  border-width: 10px 0 10px 10px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent white;
}

.right::before {
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 30px;
  border: medium solid white;
  border-width: 10px 10px 10px 0;
  border-color: transparent white transparent transparent;
}

.right::after {
  left: -16px;
}

.content {
  padding: 20px 30px;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="timeline">
  <div class="container left">
    <div class="content">
      <h2>2017</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum..</p>
    </div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
  </div>
  <div class="container right">
    <div class="content">
      <h2>2016</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum..</p>
    </div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
  </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x6m4tvdu/)

[Updated Fiddle with Adjacent images](https://jsfiddle.net/xw4h9oz8/)

Comment: This already helped a lot!
But is it possible to place the image on the opposite/other side of the vertical (time-)line to the text? When the text is left, I would like to have the image next to it on the right side of the vertical line - if the text is right, I would like to have the image for it on the left side of the vertical line.

Comment: I added new [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xw4h9oz8/) with images on the opposite direction

Comment: You can accept the answer if this helped to solve your issue.